# Datalayer Daynamic values are not coming in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am new to GTM. I am facing issue while passing dynamic values to google analytics from GTM datalayer. event name declared in datalayer is coming in analytics, static values are also coming but dynamic values from datalayer is not coming in analytics. I am using custom Html to push event and values to datalayer my website don't have datalayer code integrated.Below are my code

Custom Html Code:

[image]

Trigger to fire custom Html

[image]

Tag to fire datalayer values to Analytics

[image]

Custom Event for Tag

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your setting for `ambient` is a string not a datalayer variable.

---

You have the datalayer `page.amtient`. So you need to create a datalayer variable in GTM to receive it.

[image]

Then modify your GA4 tag.

[image]

This should work.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It is working now.